# How to redirect to a page with ionic 2 without push/popping

Tags: angular, navigation, ionic2

I am building an application with Ionic 2. Once successfully logged in, the home page is pushed on top of the login page. The only problem with this is that the "back" icon appears at the top of the home page. I want a way of redirecting to the home page upon login such that the "back" icon does not appear.

Thanks

Comment: After succesfull login, use navcontroller.setRoot instead of navcontroller.push

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png that way the rest of the community can benefit from it.

Answer (score 10):

You have to `setRoot`. That way the new component is the root, which in your case would be the HomePage component.

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePageComponent, {}, {animate: true, direction: 'forward'});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend setting the root of the navigation stack by calling `this.navCtrl.setRoot(YourDesiredPageClassHere)` on the NavigationController instance instead of calling `this.navCtrl.push(YourDesiredPageClass)`. This sets the root navigation page to YourDesiredPageClass, without any pages it can navigate back to, thus no back button.

You could also disable the back button programmatically by calling `showBackButton(false)` on the ViewController instance of the page you are navigating to like so:

```
import { NavController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class Page {

    constructor(
        private navCtrl: NavController, 
        private viewCtrl: ViewController
    ) { }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.viewCtrl.showBackButton(false);
    }
}
```

Or disable the back button in your HTML using the `hideBackButton` attribute (this could also be `hide-back-button`) like so:

```
<ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that hidding the back button won't work if you use the physical back button on Android. I guess that setting the page as Root is the only way to do it (and if you can't do it, it seems like the design of the app is not the right one...)

Comment: You have a good point @sebaferreras, so I would advise setRoot as well in this case to entirely avoid the user going back to the previous page.